# How to filter array to match array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have list of permissions :

```
const all_permissions = [
    {
        permission_id: 1,
        permission_name: "Getting User List",
        permission_method: "GET",
        permission_url: /^\/panel\/user$/
    },
    {
        permission_id: 2,
        permission_name: "Getting User Info",
        permission_method: "GET",
        permission_url: /^\/panel\/user\/[0-9]+$/
    },
    {
        permission_id: 3,
        permission_name: "Testing",
        permission_method: "GET",
        permission_url: /^\/panel\/test\/[a-z]+$/
    }
]

const my_permissions = [1,2]
```

How to filter all_permissions to match only the id inside my_permissions?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: JS uses camelCase, not snake_case for variable names.

Comment: I use camelCase for function naming only. It's my preference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

- Loop through `all_permission` array using filter
- inside filter check for `permission_id` in `my_permission` array if it's there return `true` else return `false`

```js
const all_permissions = [{permission_id: 1,permission_name: "Getting User List",permission_method: "GET",permission_url: /^\/panel\/user$/},{permission_id: 2,permission_name: "Getting User Info",permission_method: "GET",permission_url: /^\/panel\/user\/[0-9]+$/},{permission_id: 3,permission_name: "Testing",permission_method: "GET",permission_url: /^\/panel\/test\/[a-z]+$/}]
const my_permissions = [1,2]

let op = all_permissions.filter(({permission_id})=> my_permissions.includes(permission_id))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Thanks, I choose this as this is most simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`Array​.prototype​.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array​.prototype​.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const all_permissions = [
    {
        permission_id: 1,
        permission_name: "Getting User List",
        permission_method: "GET",
        permission_url: /^\/panel\/user$/
    },
    {
        permission_id: 2,
        permission_name: "Getting User Info",
        permission_method: "GET",
        permission_url: /^\/panel\/user\/[0-9]+$/
    },
    {
        permission_id: 3,
        permission_name: "Testing",
        permission_method: "GET",
        permission_url: /^\/panel\/test\/[a-z]+$/
    }
]

const my_permissions = [1,2];
const match = all_permissions.filter(p => my_permissions.includes(p.permission_id));
console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like so:

```js
const all_permissions = [{permission_id:1,permission_name:"Getting User List",permission_method:"GET",permission_url:/^\/panel\/user$/},{permission_id:2,permission_name:"Getting User Info",permission_method:"GET",permission_url:/^\/panel\/user\/[0-9]+$/},{permission_id:3,permission_name:"Testing",permission_method:"GET",permission_url:/^\/panel\/test\/[a-z]+$/}];
const my_permissions = [1,2];

const res = all_permissions.filter(({ permission_id }) => my_permissions.includes(permission_id));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var all_permissions = [{permission_id:1,permission_name:"Getting User List",permission_method:"GET",permission_url:/^\/panel\/user$/},{permission_id:2,permission_name:"Getting User Info",permission_method:"GET",permission_url:/^\/panel\/user\/[0-9]+$/},{permission_id:3,permission_name:"Testing",permission_method:"GET",permission_url:/^\/panel\/test\/[a-z]+$/}];
var my_permissions = [1,2];

var res = all_permissions.filter(function(item) {
  return my_permissions.indexOf(item.permission_id) > -1;
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```